# How to Avoid Common Repetition of Methods while Inheriting Class/Interfaces?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

Suppose I have a class Store which is a super class of 3 classes ( Book , Clothes , Food) , Now I want to add 2 common methods (Description and Price) commonly in all of them and only want to add (calculate tax) method in Food class ....
In Main class

Create array of super reference and then on each reference I have different objects of classes randomly but WHAT I WANT IS THAT I DON'T WANT TO HAVE (calculate tax ) method in Book and clothes , I only want it in Food reference(from array) .

How to achieve this goal by Dynamic Method Dispatch and Interfaces ?

Thanks indeed

Comment: You mean you have three classes extending Store, right? Store can't extend three classes. (It sounds like that should be StoreItem or something similar, too... a book isn't a store.)

Comment: Next, if you call `calculateTax` via a Store reference, what do you want it to do if it's *not* a reference to a Food object?

Comment: Oops yes i will correct it

Comment: I don't want to have any other method which isn't necessary for its self .

Comment: What’s wrong with book stores and clothing stores simply reporting that they charge zero tax?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a default method in the `Store` class. If it is not overridden by the child class it will throw an error only when called.

```
public interface Store {
    default double calculateTax() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Operation not defined for this store");
    }
    ...
}
```

When you define `Food` you can override this method:

```
public class Food implements Store {
    @Override
    public double calculateTax() {
        // calculate tax...
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Another alternative would be extending the `Store` interface to add the extra method

```
public interface Store { 
    ...
} 

public interface TaxedStore extends Store {
    double calculateTax();
    ...
}
```

Now when you define classes like `Food` you can implement `TaxedStore` and when you define classes like `Book` you can implement `Store`.